# Node js response.write(average size html) takes forever for page to load

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

This is a simple web scraper.

The HTTP request is sent by NodeJS and response to the client with HTML. The console show body.toString() immediately, but on the browser it loads forever, when I stop the server, it display the page.

I did the similar things in express, it just works, but for some reason, I am not allowed to use express. So I have to write in pure NodeJS.

I have also tried to do it without HTTP request, only left the function response.write and response.end in the if statement, it is fine when I put a few strings in response.write, but when I put minify HTML inside response.write, same situation happen, loading takes forever and display the page when I stop the server.

The following is my code, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
    const url = require("url"),
      http = require('http');

    const port = 3000;  

    const requestHandler = (request, response) => {

      if (request.url === "/") {

        const options = {
          "method": "GET",
          "hostname": "something.com",
          "port": null,
          "path": "/",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
          }
        };

        const req = http.request(options, function (res) {
          let chunks = [];

          res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
          });

          res.on("end", function () {
            let body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            console.log(body.toString());
            const html = body.toString();

            response.write(html);
            response.end();

          });
        });

        req.write("");
        req.end();

      }

    }

    const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('something bad happened', err)
      }

      console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
    })
```

Comment: I see a couple of issues. I couldn't guarantee without trying them that they're the problem, but: 1. I don't see any reason to save up the chunks, just send them through as you get them (ensuring that your response is served with the same content type and encoding as the response you're receiving), and 2. You're converting the buffer to a string without respect to encoding, then sending that string. 3. You're starting a multipart response with a boundary, but I don't see an ending boundary. I'm a bit weak in that area, but shouldn't there be an ending boundary?

Comment: The response.write acts like the same without the request part, as described in the third paragraph, it just loads forever, this is the strangest stuff, I need some guidance on sending chuck through, I started from express and helpless without it. 

I save the data for creating a static file, for the second request it will be serving the client with the local file or on redis.

Comment: Why don't you just pipe the res data to response? res.pipe(response);

Comment: I put res.pipe(response) just under the let chunks = [] and remove response.write(html)
The same things happen, but when I use 
        response.writeHead(200, {
             "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        });
it response quickly.